# Is there a name for expressions that have only a single type of operator?

Tags: notation, terminology, computer-science

For example

```
a op b op c op d op e
```

Here `a`,`b`..,`e` are different inputs. `op` is the same operator used repeatedly.

---

Some more context:
My audience is software engineers. 
`op` is associative.

I am looking for a good name to use in an interface that needs to store expressions like the following

```
a AND b AND c AND d ...
a OR b OR c OR d  ....
```

I would like to represent this expression with the following object:

```
{
   operator: AND
   inputs: [a, b ,c ,d]
}
```

I am looking for a good name to use while referring to the type of this object.

Is it a `repeated operator expression` or a `an expression with a single type of operator` or something else? I thought the mathematics community may have a good name for it.

Comment: Could you give more context? (e.g. why do you need such a term? What kind of audience are you trying to communicate with? Is `op` associative?) You *might* be looking for the word "fold" which is an operation taking `op` and a list `{a,b,c,d,e}` and producing the expression you give (parenthesized in some fixed way), but it's hard to tell from what little context there is in the question.

Comment: I'm not aware of a mathematical term. However, since this question is tagged as cs, I'll add that I've heard syntax such as this operator chaining or [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) in some languages.

Comment: Thanks @GerryMyerson fixed the typos

Comment: Maybe *nested*?

Comment: If AND and OR are the only operators your interface actually supports, I'd recommend keeping the terminology more concrete and just calling these expressions conjunctions and disjunctions, respectively. As the first commenter said, "[fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function))" is also accurate (and slightly more general as it applies to non-associative operations) and recognizable to engineers with exposure to functional programming. "Repeated operator expression" also seems fine.